# Improving the Execution speed of RSA Algorithm for polynomials with large exponents

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, encryption, cryptography

I have been developing a code to encrypt a random coefficient of polynomial c(x) in pointwise representation using RSA. it works pretty quickly for polynomials of degree bounds ranging from 4 to 32 but from a bound of 64 onwards it takes too long to encrypt and decrypt the polynomial equation. sometimes it takes more than an hour or so. Is there any way to reduce this time in my code to work for larger exponential values?

my code:

```
# Import necessary libraries
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa, padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
import numpy as np
import cv2
import cmath
import time
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
# Task i: Generate random coefficients for two polynomials
def generate_coefficients(degree_bound=2048):
    coefficients_A = np.random.rand(degree_bound)
    coefficients_B = np.random.rand(degree_bound)
    return coefficients_A, coefficients_B

# Generate random degree_bound from the specified range
degree_bound_range = [4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048]
random_degree_bound = np.random.choice(degree_bound_range)

# Generate random coefficients for two polynomials using the random degree_bound
coefficients_A, coefficients_B = generate_coefficients(degree_bound=random_degree_bound)

# Print the degree_bound and coefficients of A(x) and B(x)
print("Randomly chosen degree_bound:", random_degree_bound)
print()
print("Coefficients of A:", coefficients_A)
print()
print("Coefficients of B:", coefficients_B)
# Task i: Compute the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) coefficients of a polynomial
def dft_coefficients(coefficients, precision=10):
    n = len(coefficients)
    dft_coeffs = np.zeros(n, dtype=complex)

    vander_matrix = np.vander(np.exp(-2j * np.pi * np.arange(n) / n), N=n, increasing=True)

    for k in range(n):
        dft_coeffs[k] = np.dot(vander_matrix[k, :], coefficients)

    dft_coeffs = np.around(dft_coeffs, decimals=precision)
    return dft_coeffs

# Compute DFT coefficients of A(x) and B(x)
dft_coeffs_A = dft_coefficients(coefficients_A)
dft_coeffs_B = dft_coefficients(coefficients_B)
print("Coefficients of dft of A: ",dft_coeffs_A)
print()
print("Coefficients of dft of B: ",dft_coeffs_B)

# Task ii: Compute the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) coefficients of a polynomial
def fft_coefficients(coefficients):
    n = len(coefficients)

    if n == 1:
        return coefficients

    even_coeffs = coefficients[0::2]
    odd_coeffs = coefficients[1::2]

    even_dft_coeffs = fft_coefficients(even_coeffs)
    odd_dft_coeffs = fft_coefficients(odd_coeffs)

    dft_coeffs = np.zeros(n, dtype=complex)
    for k in range(n // 2):
        factor = np.exp(-2j * np.pi * k / n)
        dft_coeffs[k] = even_dft_coeffs[k] + factor * odd_dft_coeffs[k]
        dft_coeffs[k + n // 2] = even_dft_coeffs[k] - factor * odd_dft_coeffs[k]

    return dft_coeffs


# Compute FFT coefficients of A(x) and B(x)
fft_coeffs_A = fft_coefficients(coefficients_A)
fft_coeffs_B = fft_coefficients(coefficients_B)
print("Coefficients of fft of A: ",fft_coeffs_A)
print()
print("Coefficients of fft of B: ",fft_coeffs_B)


**# Task iii: Pointwise multiply the results of FFT to produce C(x) in P-V form
pointwise_product_coeffs = fft_coeffs_A * fft_coeffs_B
print("Pointwise Product Coefficients (C(x)):", pointwise_product_coeffs)
if random_degree_bound in [4,8,16]:
    sample = 4096
elif random_degree_bound == 32:
    sample = 8192
elif random_degree_bound == 64:
    sample = 16384
elif random_degree_bound == 64:
    sample = 32768
else:
    sample = 524288
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=sample,
)
public_key = private_key.public_key()
# Convert pointwise product coefficients to bytes for encryption
pointwise_product_bytes = pointwise_product_coeffs.tobytes()
def encrypt_data(data, public_key):
    """Encrypts the data using the public key."""
    encrypted_bytes = public_key.encrypt(
        data.tobytes(),
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )
    return encrypted_bytes
def decrypt_data(encrypted_bytes, private_key):
    """Decrypts the data using the private key."""
    decrypted_bytes = private_key.decrypt(
        encrypted_bytes,
        padding.OAEP(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            label=None
        )
    )
    return decrypted_bytes
encrypted_bytes = encrypt_data(pointwise_product_coeffs, public_key)
    # Decrypt the data

print("Encrypted Bytes:", encrypted_bytes)
decrypted_bytes = decrypt_data(encrypted_bytes, private_key)
decrypted_pointwise_product_coeffs = np.frombuffer(decrypted_bytes, dtype=complex)
# Display the decrypted coefficients
print()
print("Decrypted Pointwise Product Coefficients (C(x)):", decrypted_pointwise_product_coeffs)
print()
print("Original Pointwise Product Coefficients (C(x)):", pointwise_product_coeffs)
print()
# Verify the decryption
if np.allclose(decrypted_pointwise_product_coeffs, pointwise_product_coeffs):
    print("Decryption and verification successful")
else:
    print("Decryption and verification failed")**
```

so I feel that it has something to do with me increasing the rsa key size each time as degree bound increases. but this was the only way i could get the code working beause when i tried to use a fixed key size of 2048 for all degree bounds i kept getting the error that my encryption process failed. How do I optimise my code to work faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encrypting using RSA directly is a mistake.  That's just not how it's done.  Especially for large payloads.

The standard technique is:

1. Generate a random symmetric key, usually 256 bits or 512 bits
2. Encrypt the symmetric key using an RSA key (2048 bits or 4096 bits)
3. Encrypt the payload using the symmetric key.
4. Send the encrypted symmetric key, followed by the encrypted payload.

Generating a key with RSA that's bigger than about 8k bits becomes increasingly time consuming.

Note that there are very specific protocols on how to perform Step 2. You don't want to just encrypt the key.  Typical schemes embed the password into a larger message with a specific format, so that the receiver can verify it really is a key.